# error - Failed to load next.config.js when running npm run build

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am running the command `npm run build` but it fails with the following error:

```
> next build

error - Failed to load next.config.js, see https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error

> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/base/app/next.config.js:45:46)
    ...
```

this is what my `next.config.js` looks like (I have stripped out some content because it is not relevant to the post):

```
const path = require('path')

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    staticPageGenerationTimeOut: 90,
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
    webpack: (config) = {
        config.resolve.alias = {
            ...config.resolve.alias,
            react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
            return config
        }
    },
    env: {},
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: process.env.URL.replace(/^https?:\/\//y, ""),
                pathname: '/**'
            },
            {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: process.env.URL.replace(/^http?:\/\//y, ""),
                pathname: '/**'
            }
        ]
    },
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en'],
        defaultLocale: 'en'
    },
    async headers() {
        return [
            // some headers
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

the error as reported from the stack trace is happening on this line:

```
hostname: process.env.URL.replace(/^https?:\/\//y, ""),
```

and `URL` is set to `https://mycustomdomain.com/` in my `.env`. What I am missing here?

I am running NextJS 12.3.1, npm 8.19.4 and Node 16.20.0